# How can an application be codesigned and yet be quarantined by Apple?

Tags: applescript, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I have a .app that is quarantined.  But I am super confused how can my .app be properly codesigned and yet still be quarantined by Apple?  I have an app called iTest.app that I downloaded from my server and made sure that it was codesigned correctly but yet it is still quarantined?  I thought that having a valid code signature was the whole point of getting past Gatekeeper?

```
MyMac-7:Downloads user$ ls -l@ iTest.app
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 user staff  238 Apr 21 08:05 Contents
com.apple.quarantine     67 

MyiMac-7:Downloads user$ codesign --verify --deep --strict -vvvvvvv 
iTest.app
iTest.app: valid on disk
iTest.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

MyiMac-7:Downloads user$ spctl -a -t exec -vvvvvvv iTest.app
iTest.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: myID
```

Comment: Try to send the app yourself by email and check that again

Comment: I have tried that many times...still same result

Comment: What's the message you receive when trying to open it? Is an "open" button included? Quarantine is normal for downloaded apps. It's the way they are treatened after which counts

Comment: Details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html